# Eurosport Player on Linux?

Tags: video-streaming

I tried a few years ago with no success. Eurosport player did NOT support Linux machines. Lately I've heard different stories (they're using HTML5 for example, which should be OK with Linux). I don't want to sign up again (my free month is gone I believe), but I'd still love to see some snooker.
Anyone who knows? I don't want to install Wine for this either, never had any success with it. If someone knows, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: You can run Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu, and I'm sure that Eurosport will work with at least one of those.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it, but a shame I have to sign up just to test though...

Comment: @BerntRibbum Had you looked into it? (thank you)

Comment: @gboffi No I have not. I run player on my Samsung phone instead, and it can cast to my SmartTV with ease. No Linux involved, unfortunately ;)

Comment: Interesting solution.Tx.

Comment: Just curious, @gboffi – did you get a notfication that I answered? I tried prefixing your name with an @, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I received a notification for you first message and another one for your second.  Don't know if that happened because you made a @citation or because the site is *too smart*. Ciao.

Comment: There is actually a help button here (right of the edit field). Looks like the @ does the trick.

Comment: You didn't get a notification from my previous message, but you will get one from this, since i citate @gboffi here. What's missing on the site is to highlight the citation, or even better: make it a link. Good to know!

Comment: Signed up today (with a 50% rebate on the yearly subscription, valid until March 21!) and works on my Linux machine with Firefox and Chrome.  Both livestream and Replay of earlier broadcasts work.  I can also select the commentary language (if available in that stream).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Eurosport Player from Russia, and it works in Linux at this moment and doesn't use Widevine DRM. But I don't know, is there a difference among different countries.
[image]